# Get Request work in postman but doesn't work in browser

Tags: php, angular, authentication, cakephp, postman

I have web application that uses `Angular7` in client side and `CakePHP` in `Api`
I was using `Basic Authentication` then I replace it with `Token Authentication` all request work fine, except one which works fine only in `Postman` but in browser it's weird because it seems that there is issue with authentication but couldn't know the reason.

The request should return a blob to download the file, so I use `FPDI` in `CakePHP` to return `pdf`

Here is request in postman

**Postman Header**

```
Date →Wed, 15 May 2019 12:02:44 GMT
Server →Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/5.6.35
X-Powered-By →PHP/5.6.35
Content-Disposition →inline; filename="doc.pdf"
Cache-Control →private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma →public
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Connection →Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Content-Type →application/pdf
```

**Postman Body**
[image: Postman Body]
**Request on Chrome**
[image: Request on Chrome]
**Working request using Basic Auth**
[image: Working request using Basic Auth]
**using FireFox**

[image: using FireFox]

**Call request**

```
    getWorkListPdf(id: number, cem_id?: number) {
    let uri = `${this.workSessionsUrl}workList/${id}`;
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (cem_id) {
      params = params.set('cemetery_id', cem_id.toString());
    }
    const Auth = localStorage.getItem("AuthenticationToken");
    let header = new HttpHeaders();
      header = header.append("AuthenticationToken", Auth);
    return this.dataService.get(uri,{ headers: header, params: params, responseType: 'arraybuffer'  })
    .pipe(
      map(res => {
                  return res;
                }
      )
    );
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy the text and paste it here either as a quote or as code (whatever fits the text).

Comment: @nkr I update the post, but Actually I can't replace all images with code/text! it won't have a clear view

Comment: Please do not create duplicates of your own questions, instead update the original one! That being said, check why chrome says ["_Provisional headers are shown_"](https://www.google.com/search?q="Provisional+headers+are+shown"), that may have something do to with the problem.

Comment: @ndm when I post that question, I wasn't able to specify the issue, if it's from `Angular` or `Api`, but this question has clear info, I delete the previous one

Comment: @ndm Thanks for suggestion, I'm having a look on `Provisional headers`

Comment: @ndm in `Firefox` , `Provisional headers` doesn't appear, so may it's not the reason :\ I've updated the post with `firefox` screenshot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that `Api` can't identify that the request which contains the required header info for Authentication, I added `Authentication` array in `AppController` to allow using both `Basic Auth` and `Token Auth` when receiving `json` request, this work fine for all requests except for this one ( Download pdf )
I've tried to add

```
$this->Auth->authenticate['Token'] = array(
                'fields' => array(
                ),
                // 'parameter' => '_token',
                'header' => 'AuthenticationToken',
                'scope' => array(
                    'User.permission_api_login' => true
                )
        );
```

again in Controller and it works fine!!. it seems that it can identify the Token now and return a valid file!

Answer (score 3):

If I fully understand you want to authenticate with a bearer token instead of basic authorization. In case you want basic, you can use the following headers in your request:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')
    })
};
```

In case of bearer authorization, you can do the following:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(your token)
    })
};
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't have issue applying the authentication, but it seems that there is issue with token authentication for this request, plz have a look on chrome request, Why there is no `AuthenticationToken` in `Request Headers`

Answer (score 1):

Add **withCredentials** true in your request.

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': "application/json",
        'Content-Type': "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(your token)
    }), withCredentials: true
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! but when use `withCredentials: true` it only send `Options` Request and doesn't send `Get Request` after that!

Comment: For sending Cookie by using Angular with php we need to add withCredentials:true. You have to do same changes in **Serverside** also.
I dont't have much idea about cakephp but you can do like this :
`private function setCorsHeaders() {
    $this->response->cors($this->request)
        ->allowOrigin(['*'])
        ->allowMethods(['*'])
        ->allowHeaders(['x-xsrf-token', 'Origin', 'Content-Type', 'X-Auth-Token'])
        ->allowCredentials(['true'])
        ->exposeHeaders(['Link'])
        ->maxAge(300)
        ->build();
}`